# How to use hadoop tools in ArcMap 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, hadoop, hive, hadoop-distributed-file-system

I have downloaded hadoop tools for ArcMap and installed. In the ArcToolboxe window the hadoop tools are displayed.
In the hadoop toolbox the "Copy from HDFS" tool is asking for an HDFS server hostname, TCP port number, username and remote file. I'm having hard time getting these right. Please tell about the values to be typed in the host name, username and port number.
I'm using "Cloudera VMWare" for analyzing the data using hive queries.[image]

Comment: I'm not experienced using hadoop with ArcMap, but these videos might be a good resource: http://video.esri.com/search/hadoop

Answer (score 3):

There are tutorials on the gis-tools-for-hadoop project [wiki page](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/wiki). You will be most interested in the tutorial on moving data from [ArcGIS to Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/wiki/Getting-the-results-of-a-Hive-query-into-ArcGIS).

If you have not seen the front page of the project, that gives an overview of the project, as well as listing blog and video resources [at the bottom](http://esri.github.io/gis-tools-for-hadoop/).

There are also a few [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) that may help you troubleshoot any problems that you encounter.

*Full disclosure, I work on this project.*